# SQL Server 2016 Express and LocalDb connection issues

Tags: localdb, sql-server-2016-express

I'm having a difficult time getting localdb running under IIS in the connection strings. I am running:

- Windows 10
- SQL Server 2016 Express and LocalDb installed

I added the following to my `applicationHost.config,` which I would not like to do if possible, but it changed the original error I was getting about not connecting:

```
<applicationPools>
    <add name="myappPool" 
         autoStart="true" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
    // Added this <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="true" />**
    </add>
    <applicationPoolDefaults managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
        <processModel identityType="ApplicationPoolIdentity" 
                      loadUserProfile="true" setProfileEnvironment="false" />
    </applicationPoolDefaults>
</applicationPools>
```

The `myAppPool` is running under `ApplicationPoolIdentity` but changing this to another level of like `LocalService` doesn't help.

I am now getting this error:

> An attempt to attach an auto-named database for file
>   C:\_sites\mySite\Databases\MyDb.ldf failed. A
>   database with the same name exists, or specified file cannot be
>   opened, or it is located on UNC share.

Here is my connection string:

```
<add name="core" 
     connectionString="Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Integrated Security=true; AttachDbFileName=C:\\_sites\mySite\Databases\MyDb.ldf;" />
```

I can verify that I can connect to `(localdb)\mssqllocaldb` if Management Studio. I was assuming that localdb meant I did not have to attach the db like I regularly do with sql if using the connection string above. I even added anonymous logon to the file security of the files just to see what would happen.

Any ideas?